# Comprobar Registro en BD (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera que me ayudaran a crear un metodo que valide si ya hay un registro en BD con el nombre del usuario que se encuentra autenticado y que este devuelva un booleano y enviarlo a la vista para usarlo con JavaScript.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos DropDownList se guardan con Ajax y se almacenan correctamente. Como el usuario solo puede seleccionar y guardar esos DropDown una sola vez, lo que quiero es que la proxima vez que el usuario ingrese al sistema, se valide si este usuario ya tiene 'Propositos' guardados por medio de un booleano y me permita hacer otras cosas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se almacena en la base de datos, el CorreoUsuario se almacena desde un input tipo Hidden.

Lo unico que necesito es que se consulto en base de datos enviando como parametro el CorreoUsuario y si ya hay algo, que el metodo creado me devuelva un booleano y lo pase a la vista para trabajarlo.

¿Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias!

Comment: Podes mostrar tu codigo?? cual es el problema que tenes???

Comment: Que base de datos es? usas EntityFramework?

Comment: Tal como lo platicas puedes hacerlo, necesitas crear un método que regrese bool, y puedes utilizar AJAX para consumirlo. Puedes ayudarme compartiendo un poco de como consultas la base de datos

Comment: Así no se  hacen las preguntas

Answer (score -1):

Tal como lo platicas puedes crear un método que regrese un booleano y consumirlo con jQuery Ajax.

El método en MVC sería algo así:

```
public bool TienePropositos(string correo)
{
    using(var bd = new Context())
    {
        return bd.Propositos.Any(x => x.CorreoUsuario == correo);
    }
}
```

Utilizando jQuery puedes consumir de la siguiente manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/CONTROLLER/TienePropositos",
                data: '{correo: "'+$('#hidden_input')+'"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrias crear una regla en la base de datos, para no hacer una consulta cada vez que guardas.
Una UK Compuesta de   [Proposito_Interno_Id], [Proposito_Externo_Id], [CorreoUsuario]
Seria

```
ALTER TABLE TuTabla
ADD CONSTRAINT  [UQ_Regla] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [Proposito_Interno_Id], [Proposito_Externo_Id], [CorreoUsuario]
    )
```

Con esto cuanto trates de insertar en tu tabla devolverá una Exception, la cual podrías atrapar y mandar tu mensaje Algo como:

```
    try
{
   // Tu INSERT
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
   if(ex.Number == 2627)
   {
      //Envias el mensaje de claves duplicadas-
   }
}
```

Comment: Muy bien esta es otra opción, solo agregar esa validación al momento de insertar.